# How to get an input value from textbox and store that in Content Tree in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore-api

I have created a textbox and a button in a View Rendering.

Now I want to know how to store the input value from that textbox by clicking the button and store that in the Content Tree.

How would I do that?

Comment: do you want to use glassmapper ?

Comment: do you want to create a new item every time or update existing (context) item